# How can we use Asp.net Core Identity with Cosmosdb(sqlapi)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am learning asp.net core and azure concepts and wanted to create simple crud application with login ,authorization and authentication feature using cosmosdb.
I am getting lots of things to implement it with sql server, but i wanted to implement using cosmos db.

Please let me know if any blogs or tutorial available on internet.
Or can post simple example here also.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to control uses' authentication to accessing cosmos db?

Comment: Yes, managing users and user roles

Answer (score 1):

The previously mentioned Github [project](https://github.com/FelschR/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDB) by [felschr](https://github.com/felschr/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDB/commits?author=felschr) is no longer maintained. You could use [this](https://github.com/codekoenig/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb) project by [codekoenig](https://github.com/codekoenig/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb/commits?author=codekoenig) as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For combing Asp.Net Core Identity and Cosmosdb, you could try [AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDB](https://github.com/FelschR/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDB) and [aspnet-identity-mongo](https://github.com/g0t4/aspnet-identity-mongo).

For implementing CURD with Cosmosdb, you could try [Tutorial: Develop an ASP.NET Core MVC web application with Azure Cosmos DB by using .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnet-application)

Comment: Thanks Tao Zhou, I have gone through the link you have gave here. And created one web application with cosmosDb backend. But now want to implement authorization and authentication using cosmosDB. I didn't find any demo application which uses AspNetCore.Identity.Documentdb.

Comment: Where can we find a cosmosDB Identiy sample?